# process a large file via multithreading

Tags: c, algorithm, large-files

There is a quite large file (>10G) on the disk, each line inside the fie is composed of a line-number and a person's name, like this:

```
1 Jane
2 Perk
3 Sime
4 Perk
.. ..
```

I have to read this large file, and find the frequency of each name, finally output the results in descending order of each name's frequency, like this:

```
Perk 2
Jane 1
Sime 1
```

As the interviewer requested, the above job should be done as efficiently as possible, and multithreading is allowed. And my solution is something like this:

1. Because the file is too large, I partition the file into several small files, each small file is about `100M`, via `lseek` I can locate the begin and the end of each small file `(beg, end)`;
2. For these small files, there is a shared hash-map using person's name as key and how many times it shows so far as value;
3. For each small file, there is a single thread go through it, every time the thread encounters a person's name, it will increment its corresponding `value` in the shared hash-map;
4. When all threads finish, I think it's time to sort the hash-map according to the `value` field.

But because there might be too many names in that file, so the sorting would be slow. I didn't come up with a good idea about how to output the names in descending order.

Hope anyone can help me with the above problem, give me a better solution on how to do the job via multithreading and the sorting stuff.

Comment: Hi. In your question the interviewer specifically stated that _"multithreading is allowed"_. This basically means that the interviewer is asking for a program to be written where you could (if you choose) control if threads are used or not, _and how many_. Your initial proposal was very close, I think (as were other posters). However, Using shell commands or other methods was not being asked for by the question. Please consider this when choosing your final answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) approach could be a good idea for your problem. That approach would consist of two steps:

1. **Map**: read chunks of data from the file and create a thread to process that data
2. **Reduce**: the main thread waits for all other threads to finish and then it combines the results from each individual thread.

The advantage of this solution is that you would not need locking between the threads, since each one of them would operate on a different chunk of data. Using a shared data structure, as you are proposing, could be a solution too, but you may have some overhead due to contention for locking.

You need to do the sorting part at the reduce step, when the data from all the threads is available. But you might want to do some work during the map step, so that it is easier (quicker) to finish the complete sort at the reduce step.

If you prefer to avoid the sequential sorting at the end, you could use some custom data structure. I would use a map (something like a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) or a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) for quickly finding a name. Moreover, I would use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) in order to keep the order of frequencies among names. Of course, you would need to have parallel versions of those data structures. Depending on how coarse the parallelization is, you may have locking contention problems or not.

Comment: Thanks for your mapReduce idea, :)

Comment: @Alcott You may have a look at [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop), an opensource map-reduce framework.

Comment: One more thing, I agree with you on that "do some work in map step to make sorting easier in reduce step", but by mention `heap`, do you mean for each small chunks of data, use heap-sort to sort them?

Comment: @Alcott Well, it is not actually heap-sort, but just using a heap data structure (you actually need to use a max-heap, a heap where the element with the maximum value is kept at the root). Once you process all the data chunks (by inserting names in the heap and updating their frequencies when a repeated name is found), you just need to pop all the data from the heap. That will give you the different names ordered by frequency.

Comment: But if all those chunks of data share one heap, then I still need to lock the heap when inserting and updating names, don't I? If every chunk has its own heap, then I have to merge those heaps in reduce step, is this what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. Locking may limit the inherent parallelism in your program (because of contention from different threads). Typically the more threads you want to have the higher the chances to suffer from contention. So, depending on the characteristics of your program you will need to decide which approach to use. If locking contention is not a problem it might be better to go with the approach that uses a shared heap. Otherwise, using a per-thread private data structure might be the way to go. Notice that in this second case you do not need a heap, since you will need to do the sort at the end.

Comment: So, if I use a per-thread private data structure, then I have no other choices but do the sorting after merging these per-thread data structures into one, right?

Comment: Basically yes, but you may want to do that in an incremental way where all the threads share a part of the cost in the sorting (as opposed to having the main thread pay the full cost at the very end). The whole process would be similar to a parallel [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do the sorting in an increment way, do you mean each thread sort its own names, when all threads finish their sorting, merge those sorted names into one?

Answer (score 6):

If I asked that as an interview question using the word "efficiently" I would expect an answer something like "cut -f 2 -d ' ' < file | sort | uniq -c" because efficiency is most often about not wasting time solving an already solved problem. Actually, this is a good idea, I'll add something like this to our interview questions.

Your bottleneck will be the disk so all kinds of multithreading is overdesigning the solution (which would also count against "efficiency"). Splitting your reads like this will either make things slower if there are rotating disks or at least make the buffer cache more confused and less likely to kick in a drop-behind algorithm. Bad idea, don't do it.

Comment: +1 more. If its on a single disk, these tools are crazily optimized for this situation.

Comment: @art I think that you've misunderstood the OPs question. The question may be ambiguously phrased, but the spirit of the question is obvious: it's a _programming_ question and a _programming solution_ is expected. The word _multithreading_ is the key here, not just "efficiency". Any question that leaves the option of multithreading to the candidate is asking for a program to be written, as controlling the threading of a solution _requires that you write the program_. Relying on the shell in this case would almost certainly be viewed as not answering the question.

Comment: @aps2012 I disagree. "When all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail". When I'm interviewing programmers I look for people who can solve problems, not who pull out their editor and compiler every time something needs to be done. The world is full of overengineered reinvented wheels. In this case it's quite obvious that multithreading will not benefit the solution unless we're talking some very special case of lightning fast disks connected to 20 year old cpus. It was probably mentioned as a red herring. "write function to add two numbers in C, the xor operator is allowed."

Answer (score 3):

I don't think multithreading is a good idea. The "slow" part of the program is reading from disk, and multithreading the read from disk won't make it faster. It will only make it much more complex (for each chunk you have to find the first "full" line, for example, and you have to coordinate the various threads, and you have to lock the shared hash map each time you access it). You could work with "local" hash map and then merge them at the end (when all the threads finish (at the end of the 10gb) the partial hash maps are merged). Now you don't need to sync the access to the shared map.

I think that sorting the resulting hash map will be the easiest part, if the full hash map can be kept in memory :-) You simply copy it in a `malloc`(ed) block of memory and `qsort` it by its counter.

Comment: what do you mean by "local" hashmap? Each small file has a independent hashmap?

Comment: @Alcott Let's say you fire 10 threads from the "main" program. Each thread has an hashmap. The main program waits for all the 10 threads to finish. The main program merges the 10 hashmaps in a super-hashmap (it could reuse the hashmap of one of the 10 threads and sum the other hashmaps) and then creates the report.

Comment: About the sorting part, after all the hashmaps are merged into a super-hashmap, sorting this super-hashmap in one shot won't be slow?

Comment: @Alcott IF it is possible to keep the hashmap in memory, then I don't think there will be a problem in sorting it quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Your (2) and (4) steps in the solution make it essentially sequential (the second introduces locking to keep the hash-map consistent, and the last one, where you're attempting to sort all the data).

One-step sorting of the hash-map at the end is a little strange, you should use an incremental sorting technique, like heapsort (locking of the data structure required) or mergesort (sort parts of the "histogram" file, but avoid merging everything "in one main thread at the end" - try to create the sorting network and mix the contents of the output file at each step of the sorting).

Multi-threaded reads might be an issue, but with modern SSD drives and aggressive read caching multi-threading is not the main slowdown factor. It's all about synchronizing the results sorting process.

Here's a sample of mergesort's parallelization: http://dzmitryhuba.blogspot.com/2010/10/parallel-merge-sort.html

Once again, as I have said, some sorting network might help to allow efficient parallel sort, but not the straightforward "wait-for-all-subthreads-and-sort-their-results". Maybe, bitonic sort in case you have a lot of processors.

Comment: You're welcome. I just think that the actual scheme of parallelization is really important here. The cool "map-reduce" reference does not clarify why the "reduce" phase can be fast with multi-threading. Say you have a thousand of threads which build the "histogram" file. When there is a "main thread", it has to process the output of all the workers "single-handedly". That is at least O(n) and almost no gain from the initial parallelization.

Comment: I don't quite understand "the incremental sorting tech" in your answer, you mentioned `heapsort` and `mergesort`, but I can't figure how they are gonna work. By `heapsort`, do you mean when one thread finishes one small chunk, it should heapsort all the names appear in it; when all threads finishes, merge all the sorted small chunks? But different sorted chunks may contain the same names, which I think makes the merging complicated.

Answer (score 3):

The interviewer's original question states *"...and multithreading is allowed"*. The phrasing of this question might be a little ambiguous, however the spirit of the question is obvious: the interviewer is asking the candidate **to write a program** to solve the problem, and to analyse/justify the use (or not) of multithreading within the proposed solution. It is a simple question to test the candidate's ability to think around a large-scale problem and explain algorithmic choices they make, making sure the candidate hasn't just regurgitated something from an internet website without understanding it.

Given this, this particular interview question can be efficiently solved in O(*n* log *n*) (asymptotically speaking) whether multithreading is used or not, and **multi-threading can additionally be used** to *logarithmically* accelerate the actual execution time.

**Solution Overview**

If you were asked the OP's question by a top-flight company, the following approach would show that you really understood the problem and the issues involved. Here we propose a two stage approach:

1. The file is first partitioned and read into memory.
2. A special version of *Merge Sort* is used on the partitions that simultaneously tallies the frequency of each name as the file is being sorted.

As an example, let us consider a file with 32 names, each one letter long, and each with an initial frequency count of one. The above strategy can be visualised as follows:

```
1. File:           ARBIKJLOSNUITDBSCPBNJDTLGMGHQMRH                32 Names

2. A|R|B|I|K|J|L|O|S|N|U|I|T|D|B|S|C|P|B|N|J|D|T|L|G|M|G|H|Q|M|R|H 32 Partitions
   1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1 with counts

3.  AR  BI  JK  LO  NS  IU  DT  BS CP  BN  DJ  LT  GM  GH  MQ  HR  Merge #1
    11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11 11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  and tally

4.   ABRI    JKLO    INSU    BDST   BCNP    DJLT    GHM     HMQR   Merge #2
     1111    1111    1111    1111   1111    1111    211     1111   and tally

5.     ABIJKLOR         BDINSTU       BCDJLNPT         GHMQR       Merge #3
       11111111         1111211       11111111         22211       and tally

6.           ABDIJKLNORSTU                  BCDGHJLMNPQRT          Merge #4
             1212111111211                  1112211211111          and tally

7.                       ABCDGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU                       Merge #5
                         1322111312132113121                       and tally
```

So, if we read the final list in memory from start to finish, it yields the sorted list:

```
A|B|C|D|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
1|3|2|2|1|1|1|3|1|2|1|3|2|1|1|3|1|2|1 = 32 Name instances (== original file).
```

---

**Why the Solution is Efficient**

Whether a hash table is used (as the original poster suggested), and whether multi-threading is used or not, any solution to this question cannot be solved more efficiently than O(*n* log *n*) because a sort must be performed. Given this restriction, there are two strategies that can be employed:

1. Read data from disk, use hash table to manage name/frequency totals, then sort the hash table contents (original poster's suggested method)
2. Read data from disk, initialise each name with its frequency total from the file, then merge sort the names simultaneously summing all the totals for each name (this solution).

Solution (1) requires the hash table to be sorted after all data has been read in. Solution (2) performs its frequency tallying as it is sorting, thus the overhead of the hash table has been removed. Without considering multithreading at all, we can already see that even with the most efficient hash table implementation for Solution (1), Solution (2) is already more efficient as it doesn't have the overhead of the hash table at all.

**Constraints on Multithreading**

In both Solution (1) and Solution (2), assuming the most efficient hash table implementation ever devised is being used for Solution (1), both algorithms perform the same asymptotically in O(*n* log *n*); it's simply that the ordering of their operations is slightly different. However, while multithreading Solution (1) actually slows its execution down, **multithreading Solution (2) will gain substantial improvements in speed**. How is this possible?

If we multithread Solution (1), either in the reading from disk or in the sort afterwards, we hit a problem of contention on the hash table as all threads try to access the hash table simultaneously. Especially for writing to the table, this contention could cripple the *execution time* of Solution (1) so much so that running it *without multithreading* would actually give a faster execution time.

For multithreading to give execution time speed ups, it is necessary to make sure that each block of work that each thread performs is *independent* of every other thread. This will allow all threads to run at maximum speed with no contention on shared resources and to complete the job much faster. Solution (2) does exactly this removing the hash table altogether and employing *Merge Sort*, a **Divide and Conquer** algorithm that allows a problem to be broken into sub-problems that are *independent* of each other.

**Multithreading and Partitioning to Further Improve Execution Times**

In order to multithread the merge sort, the file can be divided into partitions and a new thread created to merge each consecutive pair of partitions. As names in the file are variable length, the file must be scanned serially from start to finish in order to be able to do the partitioning; random access on the file cannot be used. However, as any solution must scan the file contents at least once anyway, allowing only serial access to the file still yields an *optimal* solution.

What kind of speed-up in execution times can be expected from multithreading Solution (2)? The analysis of this algorithm is quite tricky given its simplicity, and as been the subject of various white papers. However, splitting the file into *n* partitions will allow the program to execute (*n* / log(*n*)) times quicker than on a single CPU with no partitioning of the file. Simply put, if a single processor takes 1 hour to process a 640GB file, then splitting the file into 64 10GB chunks and executing on a machine with 32 CPUs will allow the program to complete in around 6 minutes, a *10 fold increase* (ignoring disk overheads).